# How can I read user's status Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I wrote a bot and need the status of all users on the server.
I found https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client?scrollTo=users

This show all users with:

```
'352....128': User { username: 'NAME', id: '352....128', discriminator: '5000' avatar: null, bot: false },
```

But there is no status, does the bot not have access to read status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceStatus

You can either use:

```js
user.presence.status
```

or:

```js
member.user.presence.status
```

It returns "online", "idle", "dnd" or "offline".